# Is possible to execute java code in AWS Lambda function that's running in python environment?

Tags: java, python, aws-lambda

I would like to use jpype or similar framework in order to call some custom java code that I can't convert to Python (Kinesis KPL libraries) from AWS Lambda function that is set up to run in Python runtime. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible but a better way is to deploy your java app inside a lambda java runtime, then invoke it from the python runtime.

Comment: @jellycsc thanks I will most likely take that route. Just curious if I was to do it the way I originally stated my question would I need to have some kind of special config in order to spin up a JVM inside the Python Lambda?

Comment: Yes, you need to set up all the dependencies to run JVM in a python lambda runtime.